# How to avoid "ORA-06533 Subscript beyond count" error when sending type object as a parameter to a PL/SQL package function into a for loop?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to send part of an sub-object named ***clauses*** from another object ***dial.det_dial.issues*** according to an index ***id_issue***:

```
   dial.det_dial.issues(index).clauses
```

I have two indexes (1,43) from two ***issues*** objects.

First index(1): 1   (or id_issue 1)

Last index (2): 43  (or id_issue 43)

And each of these indexes has a set of clauses:

An Object ***Clauses*** contains: id_clause,txt_clause,date_clause,...

The objects that contains clauses:
dial -> det_dial -> issues  (id_issue) -> clauses (id_clause, txt_clause, date_clause, etc).

Types call objects.
  Object ***dial*** contains object ***det_dial***
  Object ***det_dial*** contains object ***issues***
  Object ***issues*** contains object ***clauses*** according to *id_issue* from ***issues***

When I send the object ***dial.det_dial.issues(id_issue).clauses*** in the function I get this Oracle error:

ORA-06533 Subscript beyond count

When the loop gets the index 2( id_issue = 43) just before entering to the function.

This is the code:

```
FUNCTION recordobjectdb(messages OUT t_iax_messages)
  RETURN NUMBER IS
dial  t_vw_dial;
det_dial t_vw_det_dial;
issues t_vw_issues;
BEGIN   
   IF dial.det_dial.issues IS NOT NULL AND dial.det_dial.issues.COUNT > 0 THEN
    FOR i IN dial.det_dial.issues.FIRST .. dial.det_dial.issues.LAST
      LOOP
      dial.det_dial.issues.EXTEND;
      id_issue := dial.det_dial.issues(i).idissue;
        nerror  := pk_record_data.f_record(id_issue, dial.det_dial.issues(id_issue).clauses, messages);
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
return nerror;
END recordobjectdb;
```

I have tried using EXTEND but it doesn't works, why?

The error is before to enter to the function, in the calling from the object clauses: (***dial.det_dial.issues(id_issue).clauses***).

The index ***1*** is sent to the pack_record_data.f_record function but when it's sended the clauses with index ***43*** gets the error. The indexes are not consecutive.

The case is that the index 2 (id_issue 43) is catched but It doesn't reached in the object, I guess.

**Is there a way to go over by each index using a for loop or forall instruction or similar?**

PS: Sorry my bad writing skills, I don't speak good english.

Comment: Please review [ask]. Following that as a template for your question greatly enhances your chance of getting a satisfactory answer. Specifically here that is the definition of dial.det_dial and the entire loop in question (full code even better).  you say "The indexes are not consecutive." but the code structure "FOR i IN dial.det_dial.issues.FIRST .. dial.det_dial.issues.LAST" requires a dense index, ie. they **MUST** be consecutive for this structure.

Comment: That sort of looks like your object doesn't have consecutive entries which is called sparsely populated.  In your loop, comment out the 3 instructions and add in a DBMS_OUTPUT call to display 'i" to see if there are gaps.  If there are gaps, google .NEXT for a possible solution.

Comment: Actually, instead of "i", you would need to display the value of "i" and dial.det_dial.issues(i).idissue.  And then your DBMS_OUTPUT would show the last existing entry when/if you get the error.

Comment: The last existing entry is 43, but It looks like the object clauses is not built for this issue.

Comment: So there are gaps?

Comment: No gaps, in index 2 (43) appears the error.

Comment: Your function uses 4 types (t_iax_messages, t_vw_dial, t_vw_det_dial; and t_vw_issues). Post the definitions of those types, and if they define collections, post the definition of the base object. Also post your calling routines and the complete error message you receive.